# How to design a C++ GUI application that mostly runs tcl script

Tags: c++, tcl

I am looking for a good approach to build a C++ GUI application. Its core is generating whole bunch of tcl code and execute it through Tcl C++ API (`#include <tcl.h>`). The GUI provides an easy way for users to complete those tcl scripting tasks.

In other words, inside each callback function associated with the GUI control, it's like using ostringstream to populate tcl code and passes it to tcl interpreter. Eg:

```
bool execTclProc1(options) {
  ostringstream oss;
  oss << "package require MyPackage \n";
  string optionsForTcl = genOptionsForTcl(options);
  oss << "myTclProc1 " << optionsForTcl << endl;

  if(Tcl_Eval(interp, oss.c_str() == TCL_OK) {
    // print out some messages to the GUI message window
  }

  ...
}
```

The down side of this design:

- Hard to debug tcl code error. Since every change in tcl code needs to re-compile the C code. Although a fast way is to write and test tcl code in tcl interactive shell. But a lot of tcl code is populated in C++, not hard-coded. So it's not so feasible.
- Whole bunch of tcl code is written in C++ routines. This makes it hard to maintain.

I want to seek some insights from the community.

Comment: To be honest: That approach itself seems broken to me. Why do you need to **generate** TCL code? Generating code is a fairly complex task usually done by compiler developers. And why would you need to use C++ for the generation?

Comment: Let's say 50% of tasks are done through TCL code. Using the GUI is  for loading configuration files, setting some switches, etc. And we need the GUI to present the result in a prettier way. The rest of 50% of tasks are handled by C++ libraries. So it has to be C++ application. I just wondering is there any better way to handle TCL tasks.

Comment: Not an option since there're other C++ libraries needed in the application. It has to be C++.

Comment: And creating Tcl Packages in C/C++ and then `load` it into tclsh/wish?

Comment: On Unix, yes, we do it that way. But on Windows, we provide both interface, a text box that users can input commands just they do in tclsh/wish. Another is GUI, by selecting drop down box, and clicking buttons, users can do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use the [Tk toolkit called as library functions](http://www.gibmonks.com/practical-programming/ch47lev1sec2.html) from C++?

Also, there is [Tk/C++](http://cpptk.sourceforge.net/) - don't know how good it is.  They overloaded operator- and use expression templates so that the C++ code like like Tcl.  Pretty cool!

Comment: We have Qt GUI in place already. In my opinion, it's more flexible than Tk. So is there any reason using Tk in this case is better than Qt? Not to mention that there're still whole bunch of code written in C++ already. Like handing XML or socket connection, etc.

Comment: OK, I didn't know you had a GUI already.  Qt is my favourite GUI toolkit hands down - stay with that.

Comment: I wonder if you could store Tcl code chunks in a database so you wouldn't have to recompile your C++ every time you change Tcl code.  If you need to insert variables on thefly you could have names in your Tcl code line __FIRST_NAME__ that C++ string replace would work with?